# Ant: Rename sub-directories of the same name

Tags: java, ant, rename

Let's say I have a directory structure like this:

- animals/dog/details
- animals/cat/details
- animals/frog/details
- animals/horse/details

Using ant, I would like to rename all sub-directories under `animals` called `details` to now be named `new`.  So the result would be this:

- animals/dog/new
- animals/cat/new
- animals/frog/new
- animals/horse/new

I've tried something like this:

```
    <move tofile="new">
        <path id="directories.to.rename">
            <dirset dir="animals">
                <include name="**/details"/>
            </dirset>
        </path>
    </move>
```

But get this error:

```
Cannot concatenate multiple files into a single file.
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041213/how-to-rename-a-folder-using-ant

Comment: I don't think that relates to mine as that one doesn't deal with multiple sub-directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)'s `for` task and `propertyregex` task.

```
<target name="test">
  <for param="detailsDir">
    <dirset dir="animals">
      <include name="**/details"/>
    </dirset>
    <sequential>
      <propertyregex property="output.dir" input="@{detailsDir}" regexp="(.*)/details" replace="\1" />
      <move file="@{detailsDir}" toFile="${output.dir}/new" />
    </sequential>
  </for>
</target>
```

Comment: I had to do a bit of tweeking as my version of ant-contrib uses foreach (instead of for), but the core idea of what you had there worked great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can carry out the rename you describe by means of a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html).  For example:

```
<move todir="animals">
    <dirset dir="animals" includes="**/details" />
    <globmapper from="*/details" to="*/new"/>
</move>
```

*(There's a similar example at the end of the [`move` task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html).)*

The error you saw arose because you've mixed the single-file mode of the move task (tofile) with multiple-file mode.
There's no need to nest the `dirset` in a `path` as the `move` task accepts any file-based resource collection, including `dirset`.